# Encurtar tamanho da string

Tags: php

Existe alguma forma de encurtar o tamanho da string tipo `zipar` ela e depois `deszipar` igual a funçao base64 faz?

Answer (score 4):

Tens pelo menos duas alternativas para comprimir:

- [`gzcompress()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php)

  > Esta função comprime a string usando o formato de dados ZLIB.

  Descomprimir com [`gzuncompress()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php).
- [`gzdeflate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php)

  > Esta função comprime a string usando o formato de dados DEFLATE.

  Descomprimir com [`gzinflate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php).

Um simples teste revela que `gzdeflate` consegue obter melhores resultados:

```
$tring = "Bubu votou para fechar!";

$compressed1 = gzcompress($tring, 9);

echo strlen($compressed1).PHP_EOL;    // 31 bytes

$compressed2 = gzdeflate($tring, 9);

echo strlen($compressed2).PHP_EOL;    // 25 bytes
```

Ver teste no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/V1Tmpy).

A melhoria de resultados obtida numa string tão simples está relacionada com o fato de que a função `gzcompress()` adiciona um cabeçalho com 2 bytes e um valor de verificação de 4 bytes no final:

## Qual utilizar

Em termos de compressão, ambas apresentam a mesma performance, mas em termos de descompressão, principalmente com grandes dados, a função `gzinflate()` é mais rápida, realizado o seu trabalho quase em metade do tempo quando comparando com a `gzuncompress()`.

Em suma:

Se os dados a comprimir forem ficar na mesma máquina, `gzdeflate()` parece ser a opção ideal.

## Portabilidade

Em termos de portabilidade, a solução poderá passar por uma terceira função.

Para comprimir uma string numa máquina e descomprimir numa máquina diferente, é conveniente termos alguma informação sobre o trabalho realizado:

- [`gzencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php)

  > Esta função devolve uma versão comprimida dos dados de entrada compatível com a saída do programa gzip.

  Ou seja, a saída da função contém os cabeçalhos e a estrutura dos dados, dando-nos uma forma de "movimentar" a *string* comprimida com segurança.

  Descomprimir com [`gzdecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php).

Um simples teste revela um aumento no tamanho da saída devido à informação de controlo presente na mesma (cabeçalhos e estrutura dos dados):

```
$tring = "Bubu votou para fechar!";

$compressed3 = gzencode($tring, 9);

echo strlen($compressed3).PHP_EOL;    // 43 bytes
```

Ver teste no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/GuMGxI).

Comment: tens estas funçoes `gzdeflate` para JavaScript também?

Comment: @user3163662 Desculpa a demora, como JavaScript é _off-topic_ aqui nesta pergunta de PHP, preparei uma Pergunta-e-Resposta para uma solução destas em JavaScript: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57391/223

Comment: +1 Poxa, sabia que tinha um deflate da vida.

Answer (score 3):

Talvez isso seja o que está procurando:

- Funçao [gzcompress](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gzcompress.php): usado para comprimir uma string, retornando outra string com o conteúdo comprimido.
- Funçao [gzuncompress](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gzuncompress.php): usado para descomprimir uma string comprimida. Retornando a string original.

[Exemplo:](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1bf0cffcb4e515a384a956ded4a0fa89efdeb333)

```
$compressed = gzcompress('Compress me', 9);
$decompress = gzuncompress($compressed);
echo $compressed."\n";
echo $decompress;
```

Output:

```
x�s��-(J-.V�M��?
Compress me
```

Nota: o output comprimido ficou maior do que o original, pois o algoritmo adiciona informações adicionais à string comprimida, para poder descomprimir depois. Quanto maior for a string original, melhor será o resultado.