# Implementação JavaScript do Gzip

Tags: javascript, gzip, compressão

JavaScript e LocalStorage dão-se muito bem, mas um deles está sempre a dizer que não tem espaço.

A ideia seria obter uma solução, tipo Gzip em JavaScript para podermos comprimir a informação a guardar na LocalStorage.

De que forma podemos proceder à compressão de dados em JavaScript?

Comment: Relacionado (talvez duplicata): ["Compactar dados com Javascript"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45314/215)

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma implementação [LZW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch), muito popular, que foi redesenhada a pensar no teu problema atual:

## [lz-string](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string/)

> LZ-string foi projetado para atender a necessidade de armazenar grandes quantidades de dados em localStorage, especificamente em dispositivos móveis. localStorage sendo geralmente limitada a 5MB, tudo que você pode comprimir reflete-se em muitos mais dados que você pode armazenar.

## Utilização

Basta incluir o *script*:

```
<script language="javascript" src="lz-string.js"></script>
```

E depois chamar os métodos `compress()` ou `decompress()` do objeto `LZString()`:

```
var string = "Isto é um teste de compressão! Recomendam-se óculos de proteção.";
alert("Tamanho da amostra é: " + string.length);
var compressed = LZString.compress(string);
alert("Tamanho da amostra após comprimida é: " + compressed.length);
string = LZString.decompress(compressed);
alert("Amostra é: " + string);
```

## Exemplo

Podemos ver um exemplo, mas de notar que tive que incluir o *script* no exemplo, pelo que o trecho de código é um pouco extenso:

```js
var LZString={_f:String.fromCharCode,_keyStrBase64:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",_keyStrUriSafe:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-$",_getBaseValue:function(r,e){if(LZString._baseReverseDic||(LZString._baseReverseDic={}),!LZString._baseReverseDic[r]){LZString._baseReverseDic[r]={};for(var n=0;n<r.length;n++)LZString._baseReverseDic[r][r[n]]=n}return LZString._baseReverseDic[r][e]},compressToBase64:function(r){if(null==r)return"";var e=LZString._compress(r,6,function(r){return LZString._keyStrBase64.charAt(r)});switch(e.length%4){default:case 0:return e;case 1:return e+"===";case 2:return e+"==";case 3:return e+"="}},decompressFromBase64:function(r){return null==r?"":""==r?null:LZString._decompress(r.length,32,function(e){return LZString._getBaseValue(LZString._keyStrBase64,r.charAt(e))})},compressToUTF16:function(r){return null==r?"":LZString._compress(r,15,function(r){return String.fromCharCode(r+32)})+" "},decompressFromUTF16:function(r){return null==r?"":""==r?null:LZString._decompress(r.length,16384,function(e){return r.charCodeAt(e)-32})},compressToUint8Array:function(r){for(var e=LZString.compress(r),n=new Uint8Array(2*e.length),o=0,t=e.length;t>o;o++){var i=e.charCodeAt(o);n[2*o]=i>>>8,n[2*o+1]=i%256}return n},decompressFromUint8Array:function(r){if(null===r||void 0===r)return LZString.decompress(r);for(var e=new Array(r.length/2),n=0,o=e.length;o>n;n++)e[n]=256*r[2*n]+r[2*n+1];var t=[];return e.forEach(function(r){t.push(String.fromCharCode(r))}),LZString.decompress(t.join(""))},compressToEncodedURIComponent:function(r){return null==r?"":LZString._compress(r,6,function(r){return LZString._keyStrUriSafe.charAt(r)})},decompressFromEncodedURIComponent:function(r){return null==r?"":""==r?null:(r=r.replace(/ /g,"+"),LZString._decompress(r.length,32,function(e){return LZString._getBaseValue(LZString._keyStrUriSafe,r.charAt(e))}))},compress:function(r){return LZString._compress(r,16,function(r){return String.fromCharCode(r)})},_compress:function(r,e,n){if(null==r)return"";{var o,t,i,s={},a={},p="",u="",c="",l=2,f=3,h=2,g=[],d=0,S=0;LZString._f}for(i=0;i<r.length;i+=1)if(p=r[i],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s,p)||(s[p]=f++,a[p]=!0),u=c+p,Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s,u))c=u;else{if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a,c)){if(c.charCodeAt(0)<256){for(o=0;h>o;o++)d<<=1,S==e-1?(S=0,g.push(n(d)),d=0):S++;for(t=c.charCodeAt(0),o=0;8>o;o++)d=d<<1|1&t,S==e-1?(S=0,g.push(n(d)),d=0):S++,t>>=1}else{for(t=1,o=0;h>o;o++)d=d<<1|t,S==e-1?(S=0,g.push(n(d)),d=0):S++,t=0;for(t=c.charCodeAt(0),o=0;16>o;o++)d=d<<1|1&t,S==e-1?(S=0,g.push(n(d)),d=0):S++,t>>=1}l--,0==l&&(l=Math.pow(2,h),h++),delete a[c]}else for(t=s[c],o=0;h>o;o++)d=d<<1|1&t,S==e-1?(S=0,g.push(n(d)),d=0):S++,t>>=1;l--,0==l&&(l=Math.pow(2,h),h++),s[u]=f++,c=String(p)}if(""!==c){if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a,c)){if(c.charCodeAt(0)<256){for(o=0;h>o;o++)d<<=1,S==e-1?(S=0,g.push(n(d)),d=0):S++;for(t=c.charCodeAt(0),o=0;8>o;o++)d=d<<1|1&t,S==e-1?(S=0,g.push(n(d)),d=0):S++,t>>=1}else{for(t=1,o=0;h>o;o++)d=d<<1|t,S==e-1?(S=0,g.push(n(d)),d=0):S++,t=0;for(t=c.charCodeAt(0),o=0;16>o;o++)d=d<<1|1&t,S==e-1?(S=0,g.push(n(d)),d=0):S++,t>>=1}l--,0==l&&(l=Math.pow(2,h),h++),delete a[c]}else for(t=s[c],o=0;h>o;o++)d=d<<1|1&t,S==e-1?(S=0,g.push(n(d)),d=0):S++,t>>=1;l--,0==l&&(l=Math.pow(2,h),h++)}for(t=2,o=0;h>o;o++)d=d<<1|1&t,S==e-1?(S=0,g.push(n(d)),d=0):S++,t>>=1;for(;;){if(d<<=1,S==e-1){g.push(n(d));break}S++}return g.join("")},decompress:function(r){return null==r?"":""==r?null:LZString._decompress(r.length,32768,function(e){return r.charCodeAt(e)})},_decompress:function(r,e,n){var o,t,i,s,a,p,u,c,l=[],f=4,h=4,g=3,d="",S=[],m=LZString._f,v={val:n(0),position:e,index:1};for(t=0;3>t;t+=1)l[t]=t;for(s=0,p=Math.pow(2,2),u=1;u!=p;)a=v.val&v.position,v.position>>=1,0==v.position&&(v.position=e,v.val=n(v.index++)),s|=(a>0?1:0)*u,u<<=1;switch(o=s){case 0:for(s=0,p=Math.pow(2,8),u=1;u!=p;)a=v.val&v.position,v.position>>=1,0==v.position&&(v.position=e,v.val=n(v.index++)),s|=(a>0?1:0)*u,u<<=1;c=m(s);break;case 1:for(s=0,p=Math.pow(2,16),u=1;u!=p;)a=v.val&v.position,v.position>>=1,0==v.position&&(v.position=e,v.val=n(v.index++)),s|=(a>0?1:0)*u,u<<=1;c=m(s);break;case 2:return""}for(l[3]=c,i=c,S.push(c);;){if(v.index>r)return"";for(s=0,p=Math.pow(2,g),u=1;u!=p;)a=v.val&v.position,v.position>>=1,0==v.position&&(v.position=e,v.val=n(v.index++)),s|=(a>0?1:0)*u,u<<=1;switch(c=s){case 0:for(s=0,p=Math.pow(2,8),u=1;u!=p;)a=v.val&v.position,v.position>>=1,0==v.position&&(v.position=e,v.val=n(v.index++)),s|=(a>0?1:0)*u,u<<=1;l[h++]=m(s),c=h-1,f--;break;case 1:for(s=0,p=Math.pow(2,16),u=1;u!=p;)a=v.val&v.position,v.position>>=1,0==v.position&&(v.position=e,v.val=n(v.index++)),s|=(a>0?1:0)*u,u<<=1;l[h++]=m(s),c=h-1,f--;break;case 2:return S.join("")}if(0==f&&(f=Math.pow(2,g),g++),l[c])d=l[c];else{if(c!==h)return null;d=i+i[0]}S.push(d),l[h++]=i+d[0],f--,i=d,0==f&&(f=Math.pow(2,g),g++)}}};"undefined"!=typeof module&&null!=module&&(module.exports=LZString);


var string = "Isto é um teste de compressão! Recomendam-se óculos de proteção.";
alert("Tamanho da amostra é: " + string.length);
var compressed = LZString.compress(string);
alert("Tamanho da amostra após comprimida é: " + compressed.length);
string = LZString.decompress(compressed);
alert("Amostra é: " + string);
```

## Saber mais

informação adicional pode ser consultada no [GitHub](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string) ou no [Site](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) do [@pieroxy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1480910/pieroxy), autor da lz-string.

Comment: esta funciona como a `gzdeflate`? pois queria usar esta no servidor e 'descompressionar' no client com uma funçao js

Comment: @user3163662 A solução aqui presente é para JavaScript. Para passar de JavaScript para PHP e vice-versa, podes usar esta implementação: https://github.com/nullpunkt/lz-string-php

Comment: Cuidado com esse método `compress` pois ele é específico do WebKit, não sendo [necessariamente] portável. Veja [essa minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45319/215) para mais detalhes.